# How to select all fields of first entity and single field of the joined entity

Tags: orm, nestjs, typeorm

I use Nest.JS with TypeORM and I have `User` table with a lot of columns and another table `UserType` with several fields such as `id` and  `value` and few others. Each User must have a UserType so it's a many-to-one relation. I'd like to have in the result object all User data together with `id` and `value` as a plain object:

```
@Entity("user")
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({unique: true})
  username: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Order, entity => entity.id, { nullable: false, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({name: 'type_id'})
  userType: UserType;
```

and

```
@Entity("usertype")
export class Order {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "value"})
  value: string;
...
}
```

I am trying this:

```
   const user = await this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoin("user.userType", "types")
      .addSelect(['types.id', 'types.value'])
      .where("user.id = :id", {id: id})
      .getOne();
```

But it gives:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "johnsmith",
    ....
    "userType": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "something"
    }
}
```

And I would like to have plain object like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "johnsmith",
    ....
    "userTypeId": "1",
    "userTypeValue: "something"
}
```

Is it possible without adding new fields to User?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution more like by accident:

```
this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select(['user.*', 'types.id AS typeId', 'types.value AS typeValue'])
      .leftJoin("user.userType", "types")
      .where("user.id = :id", {id: id})
      .getRawOne();
```

1. It would be nice to update typeORM documentation and remark that syntax
   `.select(['user.*']` let's select all columns of a table.
2. It's kind of strange that if you run:

```
this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .getRawOne();
```

you get sth like:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_username": "johnsmith",
    ...
    "user_isAdmin": 0,
    "user_type_id": 1
}
```

But if you add  `.select(['user.*']`:

```
this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select(['user.*']
      .getRawOne();
```

it changes names of columns completely:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "johnsmith",
    ...
    "isAdmin": 0,
    "order_id": 1
}
```

3. It's not clear from typeORM docs how to use alias syntax in .select() statement with array argument. Finally I found the syntax
   `.select(['type.id AS typeId', 'type.value AS typeValue'])`
   on Stackoverflow in a godforsaken thread and put the puzzle together.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getRawOne to do this, the [doc](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#how-to-create-and-use-a-querybuilder) already mentioned it